# HTML - spinner object goes out of scope after clicking "Submit"

Tags: javascript, html, spin.js

I have a HTML page with a `text input` and a `submit button`.

```
<form name="form1" onsubmit="startSpinner()">
    <input type="text" name="fname" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I am creating a spinner using `spin.js` as follows in the `startSpinner` function

```
function startSpinner() {

        var opts = {
            lines: 17, // The number of lines to draw
            length: 30, // The length of each line
            width: 20, // The line thickness
            radius: 60, // The radius of the inner circle
            corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
            rotate: 90, // The rotation offset
            direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
            color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
            speed: 0.8, // Rounds per second
            trail: 33, // Afterglow percentage
            shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
            hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
            className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
            zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
            top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
            left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
        };
        var target = document.getElementById('spinner_span');
        var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
    }
```

When I click `Submit` the spinner apears briefly (~1 sec) and then stops. I checked in the console - the spinner object is no longer in scope. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the page is actually being re-requested from the server.

Comment: are you trying to do ajax?

Comment: Eventually I would like to call a function in an external javascript(which will make an AJAX call), show the spinner while I wait for the results and stop the spinner.

Comment: try returning false from `startSpinner`. You won't get the values back on your server however.

Comment: What I don't understand is if the form is being requested why am I unable to get reference to elements. For eg. `document.getElementById("spinner_span")` gives me undefined

Comment: please provide more context.

Comment: Ok ignore my previous comment, I didn't check properly. Ignoring AJAX for now, how can make it work for just a stand alone HTML page. i.e Click a button -> start spinner -> stop spinner after 5 secs? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can preventDefault or return false on the form. This will stop it from submitting so the page will not be requested again.